# Do in Background Swift

Tags: ios, swift, multithreading

i have a small project with iOS and Webservice, i tried to load data from webservice when open this app. So when data is loading, UIthread will be "PAUSE"... So how i can do it in background like AsyncTask in Android?

```
self.conectDataNew.DemoSVNew("Movie", field: "IDMovie,Image,NameViet,Point", condition: "Year|DESC,Limit|7,IDState|2", request: "") { (stringData) in
        let dataArray = stringData.componentsSeparatedByString("|")
        let decodedData = NSData(base64EncodedString: dataArray[2], options: NSDataBase64DecodingOptions(rawValue: 0))
        let decodedString = NSString(data: decodedData!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
        let dataArr = decodedString!.componentsSeparatedByString("<row>")
        for i in 0...dataArr.count-1 {
            let menu = dataArr[i].componentsSeparatedByString("|")
            let url:NSURL = NSURL(string: menu[1])!
            let dt :NSData = NSData(contentsOfURL: url)!
            self.idNew.append(menu[0])
            self.posterNew.append(dt)
            self.namesNew.append(menu[2])
            self.scoreNew.append(menu[3])

        }
        self.clvNew?.reloadData()
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried googling `swift asynchronous`? Which yields https://www.raywenderlich.com/79149/grand-central-dispatch-tutorial-swift-part-1 as first result!

Comment: dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(Int(QOS_CLASS_USER_INITIATED.value), 0)) { // 1
    let overlayImage = self.faceOverlayImageFromImage(self.image)
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) { // 2
      self.fadeInNewImage(overlayImage) // 3
    }
  }

is this method? where is do in background?

Comment: **Read the tutorial**, nothing more to say.

Answer (score 0):

The best way you can do is to implement your project with [Alamofire](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire)

Alamofire is an HTTP networking library written in Swift. 
Networking in Alamofire is done asynchronously. This is an example:

```
Alamofire.request(.GET, "https://httpbin.org/get", parameters: ["foo": "bar"])
         .responseData { response in
             print(response.request)
             print(response.response)
             print(response.result)
          }
```

P.S. Look also this official document section ["Response serialization"](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire#response-serialization) to understand what type of response you can handle (string, JSON, Data,..)